# Equality of Polynomials in several variables.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Let $\mathbb{K}$ be a field and $\mathbb{K}$[$T_1,...,T_n$] the ring of polynomials in n-variables.

Assume $p, q\in \mathbb{K}$[$T_1,...,T_n$] and $U\subset\mathbb{K^n}$ such that $\forall x\in$ U holds :

$$ p(x) = q(x) $$

Which are actually the minimal requirements on U, so that we can conclude, that $p=q$?. 
I just started learning algebraic geometry (in the classical sense) and this honestly confuses me a lot sometimes.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact condition is that $U$ be "Zariski-dense", that is, a dense subset of the affine variety $\Bbb K^n$ in the [Zariski topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zariski_topology). The subset $V\subset \Bbb K^n$ given by $V=\{x\in\Bbb K^n\colon (p-q)(x)=0\}$ shows that Zariski-density is necessary (at least without using special properties of the polynomials $p$ and $q$). Admittedly, this might shed more light on the Zariski topology than on your original question....

Comment: Thank you, this actually helped me a lot!!!